# Pagination for custom post type giving 404 error (but only for news page)

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

**Before you say this is a duplicate of another question please hear me out.**

I have a custom post type on a site I'm building.

When adding pagination to the page (domain.com/news) it gives me a 404 error when trying to view anything other than the first page (domain.com/news/page/2/).

BUT... if I create a test page (domain.com/test), add the **same** news feed there and also add the pagination it works perfectly! (domain.com/test/page/2/).

Puzzling... I can't workout what's different between the two pages.

I've tried saving permalink settings to flush the cache there, have flushed the site cache, have tried various mods to rewrite rules in functions.php but nothing has worked.

**Any thoughts or ideas?**

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Comment: What is `/news`? The post type archive? Do you have a Page (post type `page`) with the slug `news`? "add the **same** news feed there" - how did you add it? Using a custom `WP_Query`?

Comment: '/news' is the URL of the News page. I've created a page in Wordpress called 'News', then created a template called 'page-news.php' and added a custom WP_Query there as you say. The really strange thing is that it works on a test page ('/test' created in the same way) but not on '/news'? Any idea why? Is Wordpress trying to do something with '/news' by default?

Comment: No, it's not. Do you have any (custom) post type where the `has_archive` is set to `news` (so the archive would be accessible at `example.com/news`)? Because if so, then it's possible for `/news/page/2` to display a "Nothing here" (i.e. a 404) page. However, if that's the case, then you would have noticed it when viewing the 1st page.. are you sure the template being loaded is indeed `page-news.php`?

Comment: It definitely was 'page-news.php' being loaded. I've got around it by changing the URL of the news section to be '/newsfeed' rather than '/news' which works perfectly. Very puzzling indeed! Thanks for your help Sally CJ

Comment: It's my pleasure, but if and when you have the time, you should try to find out what's causing the problem - maybe some code in the active theme or a plugin. (you could try deactivating plugins - if that solves the problem, then just activate the plugins back 1 at a time until the problem reappears)